# r statistical system setting up a lattice graph to display on black background

Tags: r, lattice

I;m trying to draw a lattice barchart that i will paste into a power point slide. For assorted reasons the slide is black so I need the text and the borders of the graph to be white. I tried:

```
barchart(
  x+y ~z,
  par.settings = simpleTheme(border="white",
  xlab= list(label = "xxx", col = "white") ......
```

Setting the text one at a time:

```
xlab, ylab, scales, key
```

Surely there is a nicer way to do this?
And the outer border of the graph is still black - what flag sets its color?

Comment: could you please fix this question by adding a reproducible example.  Here is help on doing that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  It is expected we should be able to run your code and we can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new theme where all options affecting text have a `white` color.

For example:

```
white.theme <- trellis.par.get()
text_elts <- grep('text',names(white.theme))
white.theme[text_elts] <- lapply(white.theme[text_elts],'[[<-','col','white')
```